# Setting database.savepoint in one method and rolling back in another method

Tags: database, rollback, savepoint

I have three objects ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC. ObjectA is the grand parent, ObjectB is child of A & Object C is child of B. I'm providing a button on ObjectA page layout to create/edit records for objectB & ObjectC.

I have a page in which the user can perform the operations for child objects B &C.

User can insert/update record for Object 1, insert/update/add attachment for Object 2.

Both the object operations are shown in two different page block and operations for ObjectC should appear only after ObjectB updates.

Here, the problem is I want to set the savepoint on page load & if the user cancel the operation in any page block, I should rollback all the DML operations done so far and then redirect to ObjectA page detail.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Database.SavePoint is only valid during a single execution context.  A Database.Savepoint does not persist across execution contexts.  You cannot start a transaction and then return to your client webpage in order to get additional data to post to another record.  I suggest that you collect all information for B and C and save at the same time instead of the user saving B and then moving on to C.  If this is not possible then you should implement a controller method 'Cancel' that deletes B if user cancels while entering C.  If A should also be deleted then you can add additional logic to delete.  Refer to this [Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm) in the Apex developers guide.

Comment: @Priyanka Does this answer your question