# Rollback all completed jobs in a chain

Tags: batch, asyncapexjob, rollback

I'm writing an application where I'm chaining jobs by calling `executeBatch` for the next job in the `finish` method of the previous one.

In case a job somewhere in the chain fails, I'd need to rollback the operations of not only the current job, but all the previously completed jobs. I would assume that for the current job, I'd need to initialize a savepoint in the constructor and then if an error occurs, do a rollback in the catch block. But how would I handle the jobs that finished successfully too? Do I initialise a savepoint at the start and pass it along through the chain?

I could also consider initialising a savepoint, serialising it and storing it in the database to retrieve later if needed, but I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: As far as I know, Savepoint is valid only in one execution context. Check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93996/setting-database-savepoint-in-one-method-and-rolling-back-in-another-method and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm. It is not being said explicitly, but it says that it is working only for single trigger context, what is smaller than execution context, but I can not find confirmation for that

Comment: Wow, that certainly doesn't sound good. Do I have any alternatives? I'm pretty sure I'm not the only person who's come up against this sort of issue... there must be some sort of workaround.

Comment: Well, can you describe your case more precisely? why do you needs to revert so much information? Probably, it would be more sense to mark information as invalid unless entire batch is completed? and as long as that is done -- mark it as valid?

Comment: Well, basically, I have a few chained jobs that do some processing on the same set of records. Each job modifies some values which are in turn evaluated by the jobs after it. That's why, it's either an all or nothing situation.

Comment: Can you describe those more precisely?

Comment: I can't go into specifics, but these jobs have to do with processing customer accounts, checking for delinquencies, issuing callouts, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rollback the entire batch job since each batch is considered a discrete transaction.

> **Each execution of a batch Apex job is considered a discrete
>   transaction.** For example, a batch Apex job that contains 1,000 records
>   and is executed without the optional scope parameter from
>   Database.executeBatch is considered five transactions of 200 records
>   each. The Apex governor limits are reset for each transaction. **If the
>   first transaction succeeds but the second fails, the database updates
>   made in the first transaction are not rolled back.**

More info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

> **References to savepoints cannot cross trigger invocations because each
>   trigger invocation is a new trigger context.** If you declare a
>   savepoint as a static variable then try to use it across trigger
>   contexts, you will receive a run-time error.

More on transaction control here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm

Comment: Okay... since that's established, what are my options?

Comment: An option that comes to mind would be to create your own rollback logic in the finish() method. Maybe you could keep some type of flag to keep track of the records that are being processed and the status of each of them to help identify them. You could either implement Database.Stateful to keep track of any failures in any of the batches or query records the records to see if any have the Failed flag, then roll back the changes yourself. You would need to get a bit creative on how you would do this but I can imagine it would be possible.